# ZeroMQ High Availability over SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, https, zeromq, high-availability

I have worked on a POC ZeroMQ project in C# language in which I had one ZeroMQ server and one ZeroMQ client connected through sockets (TCPIP) for data exchange and it worked really well.

Now for actual project we require two things:

1. High Availability
2. Secure transport (like https)

I have checked documentation of ZeroMQ version 4 and it seems like it started support encryption but there is still no support for HTTPS.

For High Availability I am planning to prepare two machines for server but I am not sure how routing will work as I did not find any relative sample code for that.

Kindly help with these two points.